# How can I handle errors inside of a for loop inside of a cx_Oracle connection?

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle

here's a run down of what I'd like to do:  I have a list of table names, and I want to run sql against an oracle database and pull back the table name and row count for every table in my table list.  However, not every table name in my list of table names is necessarily actually in the database.  This causes my code to throw a database error.  What I would like to do, is whenever I come to a table name that is not in the database, I create a dataframe that contains the table name and instead of count(*), there's some text that says 'table not found', or something similar.  At the end of the loop I'm concatenating all of the dataframes into one dataframe.  The overall goal here is to validate that certain tables exist and that they have the expected row counts.

```
query_list=[]

df_List=[]

connstr= '%s/%s@%s' %(username, password, server)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)   

with conn:

        query_list = ["SELECT '%s' as tbl, count(*) FROM %s." %(elm, database) +elm for elm in table_list]

        df_List = [pd.read_sql(elm,conn) for elm in query_list]

df = pd.concat(df_List)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `try/except` handling to return query output or table not found output:

```
def get_table_count(sql, conn, elm):
    try:
        return pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
    except:
        return pd.DataFrame({'tbl': elm, 'note': 'table not found'}, index = [0])

with conn:
   sql = "SELECT '{t}' as tbl, count(*) as table_count FROM {d}.{t}"

   df_List = [get_table_count(sql.format(t = elm, d = database), conn, elm)  \
                   for elm in table_list]

df = pd.concat(df_List, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: One small tweak and this worked.  `elm` needs to be included in the parameters in the get_table_count function. `def get_table_count(sql, conn, elm):`  After that the code worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all the Table Names which are in the DB, then create a loop to query each Table to get the row count.

Here is a SQL statement to get a list of all Tables in an Oracle DB:

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC;
```

Python (to make list of tables you want row counts for and which exist in the DB):

```
 list(set(tables_that_exist_in_DB) - (set(tables_that_exist_in_DB) - set(list_of_tables_you_want)))
```

Comment: I might be able to incorporate that into a solution, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.  I only want to see the row counts for tables in my table names list, not row counts for every table in the database.  The overall goal of this code is data validation for specific tables.  I'll edit my original question for clarity.

Comment: In that case, do a subtraction.  Edited my answer.